# Failed to replace the current page div content with another page div content in spring ajax call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

i am newbie to spring.My requirement is to replace the current page content with another page content in spring ajax call.
Below is my code:
a1.jsp

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'CheckAjax',
            success : function(data) {
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
                $("#result").empty();
                $("#result").html(data);

            },
            error : function() {
            console.log("fail");
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
<div id="result">admin</div>
<input type="button" id="my"/>
```

ajaxcheck.jsp

```
<div id="result"><c:out value="${model}"/></div>
```

Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="CheckAjax")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView myAjax(){
               logger.info("i am executing");
             return new ModelAndView("ajaxcheck","model","success");
    }
```

The console displays
     success
Object {view: null, model: Object, empty: false, viewName: "ajaxcheck", reference: true…}empty: falsemodel: ObjectmodelMap: Objectreference: trueview: nullviewName: "ajaxcheck"**proto**: Object

i already acheive this in my struts2 project.But i am struggle how to do this in spring?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: can you check the same after removing the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Comment: @santosh joshi,you are correct.it's work.thanks for your help.please post your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `@ResponseBody` helps because there are some predefined return value handlers which work on the return type of the MVC controller

So when one return some `Object` the  `org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` interface comes into picture by identifying
the appropriate return type handler and then delegate the handling to proper handler.

Following return type are supported return type in Spring MVC  3.2.x and above.

- ModelAndView or Model or Map or View
- String or void
- method annotated with `@ResponseBody`
- HttpEntity or ResponseEntity or Callable or DeferredResult

These all are defined in following method
`org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#getDefaultReturnValueHandlers()`

This is documented at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types